# I don't understand a count of votes on an answer

Tags: feature-request, voting, score

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131297/regex-and-csv-issues-in-python-2-7/8131578#8131578) presently has a score of −1, but looking at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/676259/hzm?tab=reputation)—concerning the reputation of his author—I see 2 votes: +15 and −2.

How is it possible that 0 + 1 upvote + 1 downvote, that should be counted as 0 +1 -1 if I correctly understood the manner to count, results in -1 instead of 0?

Comment: @Asylum My silly question isn't about reputation, it is about counting votes

Comment: No, it's about reputation. That +15 is not from an upvote, it's the *acceptance of the answer*.

Comment: What you call count is the score of an answer, which is the difference between the number of up-votes and the number of down-votes; what you see in the reputation page is the reputation gained because up-votes, the reputation list because down-votes, and the reputation gained because accepted answers. Those are two different things.

Comment: @Asylum _"That +15 is not from an upvote"_ Hence, this has no consequence on the reputation. Right ? Since only upvotes and downvotes are taken to calculate the reputation, as explained by kiamlaluno.

Comment: @jonsca _"There is only one downvote on that post, and no upvotes.
"_ This sentence made me understand. And then , i see you closed my question as duplicate. In which duplicate do you see the correct explanation you gave ?

Comment: @kiamlaluno _"This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic"_ Not at all. Where do you see in the linked page the answer to my question ? I was wondering about the score (if you prefer this word to 'count') , not about a reputation. The former is attached to a question/answer, the latter is attached to a user, they can't be taken one for the other, as you explain in your comment. Then  why pretending that my question is a duplicate ?

Comment: @ChrisF You listen the wrong side on your shoulders. Pretending that my question is an EXACT duplicate of the linked page is false and the 2 downvotes are erroneous , if for that alleged reason for closing.

Comment: @eyquem The closing reason you see is the one that has been picked up from at least 3 users; it could be 2 users voted to close for a different reason, and you will not know that.

Comment: Well, I searched with "+manner+counting+votes","+way+counting+votes","+counting+votes", "+votes+count", and I don't find any explanation for my question. But now I know I must call the count of votes rather "score", I found interesting Q/A with "+votes +score" etc

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thank you. Thanks to your well done comments , I understand things better. So, I conclude that at least 3 users have voted for an erroneous reason.

Comment: @eyquem I was not pinged by system in response to your comment for some reason, so apologies for my delayed response, I was not ignoring you.  I think that all of the information on points that I gave you is contained in the faq about reputation under the `You gain reputation when:` subsection of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238) to that question.  Your question is essentially asking, what components of reputation would yield a +15 and a -2, and from that you can infer that there was one downvote in total.

Answer (score 5):

The +15 is not given for an upvote, that is the rep increase earned for providing an accepted answer.

There is only one downvote on that post, and no upvotes.

Comment: Aaaaah ! OK . An acceptation of answer isn't counted. Thank you.